# Datefield passing None to post data form a django form

Tags: django, django-forms, datefield

I have a django form that has a datefield in it

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    #otherifields
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'classs':'datepicker form-control'}))
```

In my view i get the forms posted data

```
 post_data = form.cleaned_data
```

and try to access the date with

```
date = post_data['birth_date']
```

but no matter if i set a date on my template or not the value is always None. I use [this](http://goo.gl/G8Ql38) for the date widget throught all my Django project, and works fine in my ModelForms. But it won't say error of wrong date etc.

my django view

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST'::
        post_data = form.cleaned_data
        customers = Customer.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=post_data['first_name'],
                    last_name__icontains=post_data['last_name'],
                    middle_name__icontains=post_data['middle_name'],
                    gender=post_data['gender'],
                    email__icontains=post_data['email'],
                    telephone__icontains=post_data['telephone'],
                    work_phone__icontains = post_data['work_phone'],
                    mobile__icontains=post_data['mobile'],
                    address__icontains = post_data['address'],
                    region__icontains = post_data['region'],
                    state__icontains = post_data['state'],
                    municipality__icontains = post_data['municipality'],
                    postal_code__icontains = post_data['postal_code'],
                    country__icontains = post_data['country'],
        )
        if post_data['birth_date']:
            customers = customers.filter(birth_date=post_data['birth_date'])
```

#some other and returns

But if i `print post_data['birth_date']` I always get None. What could be wrong? Am I missing something with forms?

Comment: I had the field disabled....Damn me!!!!Careless....

Answer (score 0):

Your code segment

```
if post_data['birth_date']:
    customers.filter(birth_date=post_data['birth_date'])
```

is outside the scope of the `search` function. That could also be the reason it's value is `None`

Comment: No that was correct in my code...My fiedl was disabled in the form decleration....I changed it to readonly and now it works. Thank you for answering :)